# PHP setcookie not doing anything, ob_start() does not fix

Tags: php, cookies, pdo

Probably something obvious here but I really can't figure out why this setcookie call won't work. Cookies are enabled on my PHP installation, I'm not sending out any data prior to setting the cookie and using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` made absolutely no difference to my code when I tried using it.

Just for reference, the db.php file merely contains a script that connects to the database using PDO. Nothing is outputted and I can't see why it would be making any difference.

```
<?
session_start();
if (!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password']) {
    echo "Invalid username or password!";
    exit();
}
require('../inc/db.php');
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1;");
    $stmt->execute(Array($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password'])));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "Database query error!";
    exit();
}
if (count($rows) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $rows[0]['username'];
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $rows[0]['id'];
    if ($_POST['remember-me'] == "on") {
        $token = substr(base64_encode(mt_rand()), 0, 20);
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET token = ? WHERE id = ?;");
            $stmt->execute(Array($token, $_SESSION['userid']));
            setcookie("login", $_SESSION['userid'] . "/" . $token, time()+3600*24*365);
            echo "success";
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo "Database query error!";
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        echo "success";
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid username or password!";
}
?>
```

Edit: Here are the response headers, as you can see there is no Set-Cookie header...

```
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 07 Aug 2014 23:25:06 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Content-Length: 7
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

Comment: Debugging step 1: Use your browser’s developer tools (network panel) to see whether or not a cookie header is send with the response.

Comment: I have, no cookie is being set. Once my host stops playing up I'll post a dump of the headers returned if that helps.

Comment: Updated the question with the response headers. As you can see there is no cookie being set.

Comment: And you verified that your script goes into that if-branch where setcookie is located?

Comment: Yep, I tried to putting an echo in just after the if statement and it appeared in the response.